# Array_Push showing just the last object pushed into it

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I am trying to push objects into an array based on a response in a switch case, but the object returns the last item pushed into it, instead of the whole objects. It's a Facebook Messenger BOT application `$user_ratings` is set every time a user reply the BOT. Here is my code

```
$ratings=array();
$user_ratings=$msg['message']['quick_reply']['payload'];

switch($user_ratings)
{
    case "servicerate":
        $rates['Name']='Our Service';
        $rates['Rating']=$msg['message']['text'];
        array_push($ratings,$rates);
        $facebook->sendAction($sender);
        sleep(2);
        $facebook->recommend($sender);
        break;
    case "recommend":
        $rates['Name']='Recommend';
        $rates['Rating']=$msg['message']['text'];
        array_push($ratings,$rates);
        $facebook->sendAction($sender);
        sleep(2);
        $facebook->storeRating($sender);
        break;
    case "storeRating":
        $rates['Name']='Store Ratings';
        $rates['Rating']=$msg['message']['text'];
        array_push($ratings,$rates);
        $facebook->sendAction($sender);
        sleep(2);
        $facebook->outletRating($sender);
        break;
    case "outletRating":
        $rates['Name']='Outlet Ratings';
        $rates['Rating']=$msg['message']['text'];
        array_push($ratings,$rates);
        $facebook->sendAction($sender);
        sleep(2);
        break;
}
```

But if I do `print_r($ratings)` It returns just the last object "Outlet Ratings". Please help take a look at the code.
Thank you

Comment: And this whole code is inside some loop? Syntax looks correct, so probably problem is out if current scope

Comment: Might i suggest you simplify your switch case by taking the array and facebook actions out of it and put that functionality in a method? That way your code will look much cleaner

Comment: There’s no need to use `array_push()` here.

Comment: @sietse85 It's a Messenger BOT application, the facebook action sends new message to the user after every response.

Comment: You've told us this three times now, im suggesting an improvement to your code, if you wan't todo something with that info is up to you.

Comment: Also see heinz comments, your doing a useless method call while `$ratings[] = $rating` can achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have loop here, you have just switch case, and it return the result according to this switch case statement, so if the result is `Outlet Ratings`
it means that value of `$user_ratings=$msg['message']['quick_reply']['payload'];` is `"outletRating"` and accordingly the following code is executed:

```
$rates['Name']='Outlet Ratings';
$rates['Rating']=$msg['message']['text'];
array_push($ratings,$rates);
$facebook->sendAction($sender);
sleep(2);
```

Which pushes value of `$rates` into `$ratings` array.

Comment: Oh, okay. Its a messenger BOT and I'm switching the user response. The response comes after a user reply the BOT

Answer (score 0):

If the whole code is called in a loop or sthg, you always create a new array called  $ratings
with

```
$ratings=array();
```

if the last 'case' in your loop is the 'outletRating', only the result of this case is stored in $ratings..

if you have no loop around this, the code will only be called with the first iteration / case you have, and therefore will be only filled with the result of the first case.

Comment: Oh, okay. Its a messenger BOT and I'm switching the user response. The response comes after a user reply the BOT

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to fetch some data into an empty array based on different user inputs. You are first trying to put the rates array, (which is not defined in this code, so don't know completely about it) into your empty ratings array. What I noticed is that you can't push an array into another using array_push(). You should try instead array_merge() like this:

```
$a = array('a', 'b');
$b = array('c', 'd');
$merge = array_merge($a, $b); 
// $merge is now equals to array('a','b','c','d');
```

Which in your case should be:

```
$rates['Name']='Our Service';
$rates['Rating']=$msg['message']['text'];
array_merge($ratings,$rates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using array_push? 
You should use:

```
 $ratings[] = $rates;
```

Also, i noticed in your code that you're not re-initializing $rates, so make sure it's emptied every time this piece of code is called so you don't face overwriting issues which might be your problem here.